# Redshift copy statement losing spanish characters

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, encoding, amazon-redshift, utf

I have a csv file which containt the following value in one column:

```
Some words: camión, coche, moto
```

The copy statement is:

```
COPY schema.table
FROM 's3://path/file.csv'
IAM_ROLE 'arn'
delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 FORMAT AS CSV QUOTE AS '"' ;
```

And it fails because it exchanges the word `camión` for `cami..n`:

```
Some words: cami..n, coche, moto
```

So, it exceeds the `DDL` defined length.

Then I tried changing the `encoding` in the `copy`:

```
COPY schema.table
FROM 's3://path/file.csv'
IAM_ROLE 'arn'
delimiter ',' IGNOREHEADER 1 ENCODING AS UTF16 FORMAT AS CSV QUOTE AS '"' ;
```

and then it raises: `. Bad UTF16 hex sequence: 2255736572222C2252616E6B696E6720 6E616D65222C2254797065222C224D6F`

Is there anything that I am missing? I also changed the encoding in the `csv to utf-16` when trying the other encoding using:

```
csv = df.to_csv(index=False, header=True, quoting=csv_set.QUOTE_ALL, sep=",",
                    encoding="utf-16")
```

Comment: what is the encoding of the file you are loading?  UTF8-multibyte, UTF16, UTF32, bin endian or little endian?  Likely you just have a mismatch with the file format.  My guess is that the file is in UTF8-multibyte since the one character is morphing into two dots.

Comment: @BillWeiner the file is in utf-8. The issue is that when I increment the DDL length data is okei including the spanish characters.

Comment: So if the data is utf8 why are you specifying ENCODING AS UTF16 in the COPY command?  The COPY command's default is utf8

Comment: @BillWeiner the encoding as utf16 in the copy is a change that i did after testing with default as i said in the main post...

Comment: Both COPY statements say UTF16, I now think you meant UTF8 in the first one.  All Redshift internal strings (varchars) are multibyte UTF8 internally.  Specifying an encoding in the COPY command just changes how the S3 file is read.  To store non-ascii characters Redshift needs more than 1 byte so the varchar length needs to be longer.  The function octet_length() will give the length of strings in the number of bytes that will need to be defined in the DDL for a given string.

Comment: Yes, the first copy is wrong. Will fix it.
Regarding how Redshift store data didn't know, nice to know. I think then it is solved, the issue was related to using `length`, intead of `octet_length`. Post an answer and will mark it as solution.

Comment: Good to hear.  Redshift's storage in UTF-8 is a common misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with the DDL length is that Redshift stores varchars in multibyte UTF8 which, for non-ascii characters, takes up more than one byte in varchar length.  The function octet_length() can be use to find the byte length of string which is longer than character length in these situations.  DDL needs to be adjusted to account for these extra bytes when dealing with non-ascii strings.

The source file looks to be in UTF8 format as well so reading with UTF16 encoding will not work.

Comment: Thanks @BillWeiner!